# Different types of well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

The question is: "Find 3 non-isomorpic with each other well-orderings of $\mathbb{N}$. Define their ordinals and arrange them in magnitude." The question in ZFC, but I only know that such well-ordering exists due to AC. How do I answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $\Bbb{N}$ you can give well-orderings explicitely.

One is the standard order ("natural ordering") on $\Bbb{N}$.

Another would be the standard ordering on $\Bbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$ but with $n < 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$ (formalize this!)

This new ordering is not isomorphic to the other one, because $\Bbb{N}$ with the natural ordering has no maximal element.

I leave it to you to find a third different ordering.

Comment: But in second example you give ordering on $\mathbb{N}$$∖${1}, not on $\mathbb{N}$. Or these two are the same? Why then?

Comment: What I meant is that for $m,n \in \Bbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$ you define $n \lesssim m :\Leftrightarrow n \leq m$ and for $n \in \Bbb{N}$ you also define $n \lesssim 1$. Check that this indeed gives a well-ordering on $\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: So you "put" the 1 "ahead" for all $n∈\mathbb{N}$? If I understand correctly, that's an ordinal $\omega+1$.

Comment: Exactly. This new ordering on $\Bbb{N}$ is isomorphic to $\omega + 1$.

Comment: Than I can do the same by putting 1 and 2 "ahead" and saying: $∀n∈\mathbb{N}:n<1$ and $1<2$, getting the ordnal type $\omega+2$?

Comment: Indeed. In this way, you could even construct still more different orderings.